# E[X|Y] and E[X|Y]{Y = y}

Tags: probability

I need to compute E[X|Y] and E[X|Y]{Y = y}, but I'm not certain exactly what the computations are supposed to look like. I understand that E[X|Y] is a random variable, whereas E[X|Y]{Y = y} is a number, but I still can't figure out exactly how to perform the two different computations.

In particular, I'm looking at X, Y with joint normal distribution and parameters $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$, $\rho$ where $\rho$ $\ne$ 0. I need to compute both E[X|Y] and E[Y]{Y = y}.

The question was specifically asked in that order, so my hunch is that E[Y]{Y = y} should be deducible from E[X|Y].

Thanks.

Comment: I would write $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Y=y]$ rather than $\mathrm{E}[X\mid Y]\{Y=y\}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If you can find the value of $a$ for which $\operatorname{cov}(X-\mu_1,\  a(Y-\mu_2))=0$ then you've got it.  (But to prove that that's it would require proving that it's an affine function of $Y$.  Finding $a$ then finds the right affine function.) ${}\qquad{}$